# Build Failed : app:processDebugResources using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradle

While implementing first code through android studio I got the issues as given below.I tried many tricks and tips such clean and rebuild project but it didn't worked.Please help me out to move further.

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
```

[Fatal Error] aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@2ae4e83c of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
> Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@2ae4e83c of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.2.1-7147631.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.2.1-7147631.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.2.1-7147631/aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.2.1-7147631.
> > Could not parse POM https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.2.1-7147631/aapt2-4.2.1-7147631.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
21 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 12 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by downgrading to Gradle 4.2.0, i.e. use:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
```